# Como usar SQL invés de JPQL?

Tags: sql, spring-data, jpql

Esse semana passei por um problema, conseguir construir uma API Java usando **JPQL**, porém a minha API Java ainda não está concluída e já consigo prever que no futuro o meu projeto vai precisar de relatório, e imagine fazendo em JPQL? Vai ser um maior inferno!

O problema que tive é realizar um simples consulta em JPQL que se assemelha ao `select * from noticia order by data_noticia asc;` e tive muita dificuldade para entender como criar essa consulta, eu conseguir criar a consulta como você podem ver abaixo, e ela está funcionando perfeitamente;

```
package br.com.mdw.repository.noticia;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import br.com.mdw.model.Noticia;
import br.com.mdw.model.Noticia_;
import br.com.mdw.repository.filter.NoticiaFilter;

public class NoticiaRepositoryImpl implements NoticiaRepositoryQuery {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    @Override
    public Page<Noticia> filtrar(NoticiaFilter noticiaFilter, Pageable pageable) {

        CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();

        CriteriaQuery<Noticia> criteria = builder.createQuery(Noticia.class);

        Root<Noticia> root = criteria.from(Noticia.class);

          criteria.select(root);
          criteria.orderBy(builder.desc(root.get("dataNoticia")));


        Predicate[] predicates = criarRestricoes(noticiaFilter, builder, root);

        criteria.where(predicates);

        /*Esse é o trecho do código responsável em realizar a consulta simples */


        TypedQuery<Noticia> query = manager.createQuery(criteria);

        adicionarRestricoesDePaginacao(query, pageable);

        return new PageImpl<>(query.getResultList(), pageable, total(noticiaFilter));
    }

    private Predicate[] criarRestricoes(NoticiaFilter noticiaFilter, CriteriaBuilder builder, Root<Noticia> root) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(noticiaFilter.getTitulo())) {
            predicates.add(builder.like(builder.lower(root.get(Noticia_.titulo)),
                    "%" + noticiaFilter.getTitulo().toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(noticiaFilter.getConteudo())) {
            predicates.add(builder.like(builder.lower(root.get(Noticia_.conteudo)),
                    "%" + noticiaFilter.getConteudo().toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }

        if (noticiaFilter.getDataNoticia() != null) {
            predicates
                    .add(builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(Noticia_.dataNoticia), noticiaFilter.getDataNoticia()));
        }

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(noticiaFilter.getFont())) {
            predicates.add(builder.like(builder.lower(root.get(Noticia_.font)),
                    "%" + noticiaFilter.getFont().toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }

        return predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]);
    }

    private void adicionarRestricoesDePaginacao(TypedQuery<Noticia> query, Pageable pageable) {
        int paginaAtual = pageable.getPageNumber();
        int totalRegistrosPorPagina = pageable.getPageSize();
        int primeiroRegistroDaPagina = paginaAtual * totalRegistrosPorPagina;

        query.setFirstResult(primeiroRegistroDaPagina);
        query.setMaxResults(totalRegistrosPorPagina);
    }

    private Long total(NoticiaFilter noticiaFilter) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Long> criteria = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<Noticia> root = criteria.from(Noticia.class);

        Predicate[] predicates = criarRestricoes(noticiaFilter, builder, root);
        criteria.where(predicates);

        criteria.select(builder.count(root));
        return manager.createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
    }

}
```

Você pode perceber que existe um filtro, mas antes do filtro é realizado uma simples consulta JPQL nesse trecho de código;

```
CriteriaQuery<Noticia> criteria = builder.createQuery(Noticia.class);

Root<Noticia> root = criteria.from(Noticia.class);

  criteria.select(root);
  criteria.orderBy(builder.desc(root.get("dataNoticia")));
```

**Qual é minha dificuldade?**

Eu gostaria de fazer a consulta usando SQL, mas não sei como poderia ficar o código logo acima, já tentei fazer de tudo, mas o código fica errado, fica dando erros em algumas partes e como fiz a parte mais difícil eu acho que vai ser simples de alguém me ajuda, qualquer coisa estarei a disposição para tirar dúvidas para receber ajuda.

Comment: em.createNativeQuery("..."), você está utilizando o CriteriaAPI para gerar esta consulta.. Essa API no fim, cria uma consulta JPQL de fato. No entanto você poderia simplesmente escreve-la em vez de usar a API.

Comment: Com JPQL a consulta que você citou seria simplesmente. em.createQuery("SELECT n FROM Noticia n ORDER BY n.dataNoticia ASC");

Comment: @Israel Merljak da forma como você explicou gera erro no código Java, não funciona e inclusive já tentei dessa forma antes, a não ser que você explique como iria fica no código que foi mencionado nessa postagem!

Comment: a questão é que essa query que está no código não é tão simples, você quer fazer um filtro dinâmico. A melhor maneira pra esse tipo de query é a CriteriaAPI mesmo. No entanto se quiser fazer com JPQL (ou SQL) você teria que alterar para concatenar a String da query conforme a necessidade do filtro (o que é propenso a erro, e pode se tornar mais 'infernal' do que usar a API).

Comment: Não posso descorda de você porque ainda estou aprendendo, mas vou esperar ver se aparece mais alguém para dá uma solução.

Answer (score 0):

Como você queria ver uma possível implementação desse mesmo filtro não utilizando a `CriteriaAPI`, segue uma versão **(não testada..)** com o `JPQL`.

Adicionei só as partes do código que foram alteradas.. o restante continua identico a sua versão.

```
    public Page filtrar(NoticiaFilter noticiaFilter, Pageable pageable) {

        String baseQuery = "SELECT n FROM Noticia n ";
        String whereQuery = criarWhere(noticiaFilter);
        String orderBy = "ORDER BY n.dataNoticia DESC";

        TypedQuery query = manager.createQuery(
                baseQuery + whereQuery + orderBy
        );

        adicionarParameters(query, noticiaFilter);
        adicionarRestricoesDePaginacao(query, pageable);

        return new PageImpl(query.getResultList(), pageable, total(noticiaFilter));
    }

    private String criarWhere(NoticiaFilter noticiaFilter) {
        String where = "WHERE 1=1 "; 

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(noticiaFilter.getTitulo())) {
            where += "AND " + Noticia_.titulo.getName() + " LIKE :titulo";
        }

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(noticiaFilter.getConteudo())) {
            where += "AND " + Noticia_.conteudo.getName() + " LIKE :conteudo";
        }

        if (noticiaFilter.getDataNoticia() != null) {
            where += "AND " + Noticia_.dataNoticia.getName() + " >= :dataNoticia'";
        }

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(noticiaFilter.getFont())) {
            where += "AND " + Noticia_.font.getName() + " LIKE :font'";
        }

        return where;
    }

    private void adicionarParameters(TypedQuery query, NoticiaFilter noticiaFilter) {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(noticiaFilter.getTitulo())) {
            query.setParameter("titulo", "%" + noticiaFilter.getTitulo().toLowerCase() + "%");
        }

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(noticiaFilter.getConteudo())) {
            query.setParameter("conteudo", "%" + noticiaFilter.getConteudo().toLowerCase() + "%");
        }

        if (noticiaFilter.getDataNoticia() != null) {
            query.setParameter("dataNoticia", noticiaFilter.getDataNoticia());
        }

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(noticiaFilter.getFont())) {
            query.setParameter("font", "%" + noticiaFilter.getFont().toLowerCase() + "%");
        }
    }
```